# Angular: Erro em módulos do sistema

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

Olá! Minha aplicação parou de compilar, dando problemas em módulos de uso geral. O módulo crypto, foi o primeiro erro que apareceu, então procurei uma solução para este erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A solução que eu encontrei altera o arquivo browser.js do webpack-config. O erro do crypto sumiu mas continua aparecendo diversos erros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso seria um erro no Webpack? Eu não instalei webpack na aplicação, acredito que foi instalado junto com o angular/cli.

As versões que estou usando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara pra começar não tem como você usar o webpack e o angular-cli no mesmo projeto.... Até porque o angularcli já tem um webpack embarcado. Seu problema foi criado utilizando oque exatamente?

Comment: O webpack é o embarcado então, pq eu não instalei manualmente o webpack. O erro surgiu de repente. Apareceu que um módulo iria ficar depreciado, mas eu achei que era uma recomendação apenas, e de repente ficou assim, cheio de erros.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido! O webpack do angular/cli foi configurado para uma versão anterior do angular/cli 6.0

Arquivo modificado: browser.js

Antes:

```js
node: false;
```

Modificação:

```js
node: {
          fs: 'empty',
          global: true,
          crypto: true,
          tls: 'empty',
          dns: 'empty',
          net: 'empty',
          process: true,
          module: 'empty',
          clearImmediate: false,
          setImmediate: false
        },
```

Caminho: node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs